@sidebase/nuxt-auth - call refresh token with custom payload
How can i add more properties to refresh token request payload, currently it sending:
{refresh_token:"my-refresh-token"}

but i want to add more properties:
{refresh_token:"refreshToken", client_id:"clientId", grant_type:"grantType"}

my current nuxt-auth config:
    baseURL: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_URL,
    globalAppMiddleware: true,
    sessionRefresh: {
      enablePeriodically: false,
      enableOnWindowFocus: false,
    },

    provider: {
      type: "refresh",
      endpoints: {
        signIn: { path: "oauth2/token", method: "post" },
        signOut: false,
        signUp: false,
        getSession: { path: "api/accounts/userInfo", method: "get" },
        refresh: { path: "oauth2/token", method: "post" },
      },
      token: {
        type: "Bearer",
        signInResponseTokenPointer: "/access_token",
        headerName: "authorization",
        sameSiteAttribute: false,
      },
      refreshToken: {
        signInResponseRefreshTokenPointer: "/refresh_token",
        refreshRequestTokenPointer: "/access_token",
      },
    },
  },```

